# Часовые пояса и способы хранения даты и времени

Tags: php, javascript, frontend, backend, timezone

Как лучше передавать, обрабатывать и хранить дату и время, если от приложения требуется учёт временных зон?

Например: на странице есть таймер, который истекает в 12 часов дня по Московскому времени, это задает пользователь, когда зайдет пользователь из Уфы и у него будет 12 часов - таймер для него остановится, ведь у него уже 12 часов.

Вот мне и нужно решить эту проблему. Если передавать время в UTC - как передать смещение с фронта? Какие есть общепринятые практики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте разделим два случая: точный момент события, которое произошло или произойдёт одновременно* во всех частях света. В этом случае достаточно просто хранить универсальное время в UTC (на более низком уровне это, скорее всего, будет число равное количеству секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 г. по Гринвичу). Большинство средств разработки это умеют. Например, в SQL-совместимой СУБД вы можете использовать тип TIMESTAMP.

Второй случай: пользователь задаёт время в своём часовом поясе и не ожидает никакого подвоха. 12 часов всегда для него будет 12 часов (обычно о таком не задумываются), даже если на следующий день переводят стрелки часов (в некоторых странах ещё осталась такая практика). Для такой ситуации достаточно знать, что именно пользователь ввёл в информационную систему, и его местоположение (чем точнее, тем лучше). На основе этого можно определить и закэшировать его часовой пояс (в Москве это может быть `Europe/Moscow`) и заданный момент времени в UTC.

С временем бывает ещё вариант вроде похожий на второй случай, но местоположения нет. Например, срок действия паспорта до 15 апреля 2020 г. И как определить, в какой час он истекает?

О хранении времени весьма доходчиво писали на Хабре: https://habr.com/company/mailru/blog/242645/

* <sub>Пренебрежём релятивисткими эффектами.</sub>

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку, не плохой пост на хабре